# Regex non-digit or non-whitespace before and after a digit

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm struggling a bit to get regex put to work to replace the matching pattern.

Some examples of what it should be getting and what not.

`During 6 months` or `in 999 days` -> shouldn't get it

`birthdate: π11π` -> should get it

Basically, I'm trying to get any non-digit or non-whitespace to afterwards replace it.

I tried using this: `[\D\S]{1}[0-9]+[\D\S]{1}`. For the example `birthdate: π11π` is working fine, but for `during 6 months` is also getting matched, when it shouldn't.

Any suggestions on how to get this to work?

Comment: Try `(?<=[^\s\d])\d+(?=[^\s\d])`, see [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Csj8p9/2).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks, this should work! Going to read the info the page provides

Comment: I explained the regex in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76919661/3832970). It can have variations depending on what exactly you are using the pattern for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I imagine you would like to delete these chars around numbers as you
mentioned a "replacement" in your question.

Using a negative character class should solve your problem. `[^\d\s]`
means "*not a space and neither a number*". I also imagine you could
have more than just one character, so you could also replace
`[^\d\s]{1}` (the `{1}` isn't useful as it's already the default
number of occurrences) by `[^\d\s]+`, where `+` means "*1 or several
times*" and is equivalent to `{1,}`.

You can capture the number in a group so that you can use it for the
replacement value in order to get rid of the characters before and
after the number. It leads to:

```
/[^\d\s]+(\d+)[^\d\s]+/g
```

And the replacement is just the content of the capturing group n°1:
`$1`

In action: https://regex101.com/r/Uowh3q/2

I replaced `[0-9]` by `\d` (for **d**igit) as it's a bit shorter.

The *JavaScript* implementation:

```js
const regex = /[^\d\s]+(\d+)[^\d\s]+/g;

const input = `During 6 months or in 999 days
birthdate: π11π
Probably this one also: @@100@@`;

let foundNumbers = [];
const output = input.replace(regex, function(fullMatch, number) {
  foundNumbers.push(parseInt(number));
  // The replacement value is just the found number (drop stuff before and after).
  return number;
});

console.log('Found numbers to correct:', foundNumbers);
console.log('Input: "' + input + '"');
console.log('Output: "' + output + '"');
```

Just to mention, as you were talking about replacement in your
question, I didn't use any lookbehind or lookahead feature. I
assumed you wanted to correct the input text.

But if your intention is just to find these numbers surounded by
non-digit chars, then I suggest you use Wiktor's answer with the
positive lookbehind and positive lookahead. The execution time will
be shortened and quite significative if your input is big. This is
due to the fact that searching first for digits takes less time than
searching for non-digits and non-spaces.

Answer (score 3):

You can use

```
(?<=[^\s\d])\d+(?=[^\s\d])
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Csj8p9/2). *Details*:

- `(?<=[^\s\d])` - a positive lookbehind that matches a location that is immediately preceded with a char other than a whitespace and digit
- `\d+` - one or more digits
- `(?=[^\s\d])` - a positive lookahead that matches a location that is immediately followed with a char other than a whitespace and digit.

See also a JavaScript demo:

```js
const arr = ['During 6 months', 'in 999 days', 'birthdate: π11π'];
const re = /(?<=[^\s\d])\d+(?=[^\s\d])/;
for (const s of arr) {
  console.log(s + ' => ' + (s.match(re)?.[0] || 'FALSE'))
}
```

Comment: I have to mention, that even if this is working, when trying to replace the whole thing it just leaves me the symbols there, only replacing the digits inside them, maybe because it's not fully supported yet

Comment: @Zander Please put it clear: if your input string is `During 6 months`, what would you like to get as the output?

Comment: No no, it works. The only thing that the `π11π` is not replacing the `π` symbols. I've been searching and it seems like lookbehind and lookahead are still not fully supported on all browsers.

I had to use most common one for the moment: `[^\d\s]{1}\d+[^\d\s]{1}`

Comment: @Zander Then you just need `s.replace(/[^\s\d]+\d+[^\s\d]+/g, '')` (or `/[^\s\d]*\d+[^\s\d]+|[^\s\d]+\d+[^\s\d]*/g`), there is no need to use lookarounds in that case.

Answer (score 1):

\D matches such character which is non-digit
\S matches any non-white space character

So, `\D` & `\S` will not work here. use `\d` & `\s`.

Now your regex: `[\D\S]{1}[0-9]+[\D\S]{1}`.
If I correct your regex, it should be:
`[^\d\s]{1}[0-9]+[^\d\s]{1}` or `[^\d\s]{1}\d+[^\d\s]{1}`.

This is out put of correspoinding regex:
[image]

If you want to filter the data `11` from result `π11π`, use regex  Lookahead and Lookbehind  concept.

This is pretty much simple:
`(?<=[^\d\s]{1})[0-9]+(?=[^\d\s]{1})` or `(?<=[^\d\s]{1})\d+(?=[^\d\s]{1})`
[image]

#### I think this is better solution for you:

`(?<=[^\d\s]+)\d+(?=[^\d\s]+)`

Comment: `{1}` is always useless in regex patterns.